# Меняется cursor при включении режима различных device в google crome

Tags: google-chrome, адаптивная-верстка, responsive

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

проблема появилась где-то месяц назад, достала, решил исправить незнаю как, по сути бог с ней, но мне иногда необходимо посмотреть hover эффекты убрались ли на разрешениях экрана <992px, а этот кружок мешает... смотрю с opera...
Если кто знает или сталкивался с таким - подскажите, пожалуйста, как его убрать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что это у вас за устройство такое, что при разрешении <991px у вас по его экрану можно мышкой елозить? [Вот самые популярные](https://www.mydevice.io/#compare-devices) И при разрешении <1280px обычно считать что это планшет или что помельче, и с ним работают пальцами, собственно по тому в Chrome DevTools оно как-бы и намекает, что если ты нажал на иконку мобилки, то про мышку забудь. А в ответе на вопрос - ни как. Прикрутите к дивайсу мышку и тестируйте на практике.

Comment: Но подобный курскор появляется не только при разрешении <1200px, он появляется и при 1700px, в общем сразу же как только я перехожу в режим device, а как к нему прикрутить мышку? раньше ведь такого не было, обновление что ль... Я понимаю, что он намекает мне на другое поведение устройства, но мне нужно hover эффекты проверять))) а этот кружок игнорирует cursor: pointer

Comment: Так вы не правильно вопрос задаете. Там есть специальное дополнение в настройках если вам надо проверять ховер http://prntscr.com/qjbt1q

Comment: Простите, но ведь если я выбираю что-то из этого списка курсор то остается прежним, или я что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: Вы определитесь, вам или посмотреть как измениться значение элемента при "наведении" или курсор (который по сути ничего не показывает), и вы сами его можете переназначить через CSS свойство cursor для данного элемента. Нету в тачпадах и смартфонах по умолчанию курсора. Та другие параметры снимаются

Answer (score 1):

1. Запускаем Панель разработчика (DevTools)
2. В правом верхнем углу нажимаем три точки [image: три точки]
3. Выбираем "Добавить тип устройства"
4. Появится 4 режима просмотра[image: 4 режима просмотра]
5. В режиме "Desktop" и "Mobile(no touch)" будет работать курсор.